# procedure created with compilation error

Tags: plsql

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE ex9a(n NUMBER ,c CHAR) IS
    pi NUMBER(7,4):=3.14;
    v_record Areas%rowtype;

    BEGIN
     IF  c='R' THEN 
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('CHOICE : R');
      v_record.Input_Value:= n;
      v_record.Circle_Area:=pi*n*n;
      v_record.Square_Area:=null;
      v_record.Sphere_Area:=2*pi*n;
      v_record.Sphere_Volume:=(3/4)*r*r;
      v_record.Cube_Volume:=null;
     END IF;``
    END;
    /
```

I am getting procedure created with compilation errors.I want to compute area of a circle and insert it into the table .
When I give SHOW ERRORS , it lists the errors as 
1) plsql statement
2) 'R' must be declared .
(Even after I gave 'then'. I forgot the line number)

Comment: Please post what compilation error you are getting.

Answer (score 1):

It would help if you would list the errors, and the lines on which they occur.

However, one obvious issue is that your `IF` statement has no `THEN`. It should be:

```
IF c = 'R' THEN
```